# Aggregate observations across samples by rownames (dplyr) in R

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by, summarize, rowsum

Aloha,

I am trying to get the total counts for each row name in my sample matrix. For some reason, I have tried both rowsum and then converting to a data frame and using dplyr::group_by but they are giving errors. Here is a subset of example data:

```
mat = matrix(c(0,1,2,3,4), nrow=3, ncol = 5)
rownames(mat) <- c("CHO", "NO", "O")
colnames(mat) <-  c("sample_1", "sample_2", "sample_3", "sample_4", "sample_5")`
```

I would like to have a resulting data frame with the formula name, then the sum of observations across samples and the percent of samples formula was observed in overall.

It seems easy enough but I have tried all different combinations aggregating the data with no avail and would be very appreciative of some guidance.

Comment: YOu have unique row names. Not clear about what you want to aggregate

Comment: DO you need `rowSums(mat)`

Comment: What is your expected output for `mat` that you shared? Do you want to sum the data rowwise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We may need only `rowSums`

```
rowSums(mat)
```

---

If there are duplicate rownames (in the example data, the rownames are unique), then we use `rowsum` with `group` specified as the `rownames`

```
rowsum(mat, row.names(mat))
```

and then we use `rowSums` on top of that

```
rowSums(rowsum(mat, row.names(mat)))
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer from @akrun does exactly what the poster asks, but I find myself in a similar but slightly different situation *a lot*, but with a dataframe that has what would be duplicate rownames in a matrix, so these are now values in a column instead (called "compound" below), like this:

```
set.seed(2347813)
df <- data.frame(matrix(sample(c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9), 
                               size=30, replace=T), nrow=6, ncol=5)) 
colnames(df) <-  c("sample_1", "sample_2", "sample_3", "sample_4", "sample_5")
df$compound <- c("CHO", "NO", "O", "CHO", "NO", "O")
```

which looks like:

```
  sample_1 sample_2 sample_3 sample_4 sample_5 compound
1        0        1        4        9        1      CHO
2        3        8        3        0        5       NO
3        8        9        7        1        7        O
4        8        2        9        7        7      CHO
5        3        8        9        0        5       NO
6        6        1        6        7        5        O
```

then I want to summarize the data in various ways but I want to group it by compound, and use piping (`%>%` below) from dplyr/tidyverse.
like the original question, if we want the total by compound we would do:

```
df %>%
  group_by(compound) %>%
  summarize(total=sum(c_across(starts_with("sample"))))
```

which would give us:

```
  compound total
  <chr>    <dbl>
1 CHO         48
2 NO          44
3 O           57
```

but I think the best part is the ability to do multiple summarizing operations at once. let's say we wanted the total, mean, standard deviation, and the mean of only sample_1 through sample_3, we can get that all in one piped command:

```
df %>%
  group_by(compound) %>%
  summarize(total=sum(c_across(starts_with("sample"))), 
            grand_mean=mean(c_across(starts_with("sample"))),
            sd=sd(c_across(starts_with("sample"))), 
            mean_13=mean(c_across(sample_1:sample_3))) # mean of sample 1-3
```

which gives us:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 5
  compound total grand_mean    sd mean_13
  <chr>    <dbl>      <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
1 CHO         48        4.8  3.58    4   
2 NO          44        4.4  3.20    5.67
3 O           57        5.7  2.71    6.17
```

combining piping (`%>%`), `group_by`, `mutate`, and the new versions of `across` (above I used `c_across`) you can get a lot done in one go.